# How to enable urlManager in Yii for virtual directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii, virtual-directory, yii-url-manager

I'm using xampp and tried to put my yii folder and the webapp folder separate from the htdocs directory. I've followed the instructions from here:

http://el.web.id/how-to-add-virtual-directory-alias-on-apache-xampp-165

I was able to run the main page all right, but the other pages just return a not found status. May I know how to fix this? I'm not even sure if the main problem comes from Apache or from Yii. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I get it now. We'd just need to add a rewritebase on the .htaccess file that matches the alias.

```
RewriteBase /aliasfolder
```

This is for reference purposes.